# .Net cassette paths returning 404 in production

Tags: .net, cassette

I have the current bundle reference working locally:

```
Bundles.Reference("/Content/global.css");
```

On the development site, this resolves (somehow) via:

```
href="/_cassette/asset/Content/global.css?d8036040d7bdf16f597402da22aebe89fb415a42"
```

The problem is this is returning a 404 in production but unsure why.  I though this may have been a configuration issue with the handler but I have not set one up in the configuration (web.config) so something must be happening internally to cause problems.

Both applications seem to be running .net 4+, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong (but close) in my previous answer.  The fix was actually to add my own UrlModifier  - this doesn't append the virtual directory to the path and all is well.

Comment: I know this is old but could you elaborate? I'm having this exact issue and cannot figure out a fix.

Comment: @GlacialSpoon I've had a dig around svn around this time but can't see anything in the cassette configuration that would highlight what I changed to make this work.  Apologies, I guess a lesson from this is to be a bit more descriptive in my answers.  See [this](http://www.daveleigh.co.uk/cassette-and-cdn/), it's not the answer but might point towards it.

Comment: Honestly wasn't expecting a response but I appreciate the effort to have a look so fast. Thanks :)